# Not sure why my variables aren't working

Tags: javascript

I had the variables "ballX" and "ballY" working previously. However, I must've messed up somewhere as they now show up as "unedfined" when I try to view their values using console.log. I've spent the last 2-3 hours looking through my code and online for fixes to no avail, any help would be appreciated.(This is my first time using javascript so apologies in advance if it is something simple :) ).

```html
<html>
<canvas id="gameCanvas" width = "600" height = "250"></canvas>
<script>
 //Calling technical stuff
 var canvas;
 var canvasContext;
 canvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
 canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
 
 
 
 // Initial values
 var ballX = (canvas.width-20)/2;
 var ballY = (canvas.height-20)/2;
 var yDirection = 2;
 var xDirection = 2;
 var PositionY;
 var drawEverythingCount = 0;
 
 // Constants
 var ballSize = 20;
 var panelHeight = 100;
 var panelWidth = 10;
  
 window.onload = function(){
 
 // Calls the main draw function and has the interval for repeating set to 10 ms
 setInterval(function() {drawEverything(PositionY)}, 10);
 
 
 }
 
 //Adds the event for mousemove to record the Y position of the mouse
 document.addEventListener("mousemove",function(event){
 PositionY = (event.clientY-(panelHeight/2));
 });

 function drawEverything(PositionY) {
 drawEverythingCount = drawEverythingCount + 1;
 
 // Draws the canvas, ball and panel
 canvasContext.fillStyle = 'black';
 canvasContext.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
 canvasContext.fillStyle = 'red';
 canvasContext.fillRect(ballX,ballY,ballSize,ballSize);
 canvasContext.fillStyle = 'green';
 canvasContext.fillRect(canvas.width-panelWidth,PositionY,panelWidth,panelHeight);
 
 // Resets the game if the ball goes out of the Right side of the canvas
 if (ballX > canvas.width) {
 alert('You scored:' + (xDirection - 2) + '!')
 var ballX = (canvas.width - 20)/2;
 var ballY = (canvas.height-20)/2;
 var yDirection = 2;
 var xDirection = 2; 
 
} 
 // Checks to see if the ball is about to hit the left-hand wall
 if (ballX - xDirection < 0) {(xDirection = (xDirection*-1) + 1); ballX = 0;};
 
 // Checks to see whether or not the ball is about to go off of the canvas' y-axis and changes its 
 // direction
 if ((ballY+20) > canvas.height || ballY < 0){
 if ((ballY+20) > canvas.height){yDirection = -1;} else {yDirection = 1;}
 }
 
 // Checks to see if the ball is hitting the panel
 if ((ballX + xDirection) > (canvas.width - 10)){
 var y
 for (y = PositionY; y < (PositionY + 101);y++){
 if(y == ballY) {xDirection = xDirection * -1;break;}
 }};
 
 // Movement of the ball
 ballY = ballY + yDirection;
 ballX = ballX + xDirection;
 }

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Where are you trying to console.log the value?

Comment: I used console.log at the start of the function drawEverything so I could view the changes in the ball hopefully. However, it showed the correct starting coords then the rest were "undefined"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `if (ballX > canvas.width)` statement you redeclare your variables, this is what messes it up. This will hoist the variables to top of the function `drawEverything` and shadow the variables you declared in the top scope. In your case it'll be declared as `undefined`.

If you remove the `var` keyword in front of your variables it'll work as expected since you'll be relying on the global state of your variables.

```
if (ballX > canvas.width) {
    alert('You scored:' + (xDirection - 2) + '!')
    ballX = (canvas.width - 20)/2;
    ballY = (canvas.height-20)/2;
    yDirection = 2;
    xDirection = 2; 

}
```

This is an inherent problem with the ease of global state that JavaScript provides. There are however tips you can employ to mitigate these problems in the future. The use of [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) and [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) keywords would've helped you tremendously here.

[Working code here](http://jsbin.com/rifajekoqi/)